# Counting based on distinct column value

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the following table in Oracle:

```
Member Code Cond
1      A    Good
1      B    Bad
2      B    Bad
3      A    Good
3      B    Good
3      B    Bad
```

How do I get a result such that:

```
Code Condition Code_Count Uniq_Member_Count
A    Good        2          2
B    Bad         3          3
B    Good        1          0 (Reason why we're setting this 0 because for code B we already counted the unique member on the previous line)
```

I am just trying to calculate the total uniq member count regardless of condition in one query. Hope my question made sense. Thanks!

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding what PL/SQL is.  Are you using an Oracle database?

Comment: @sstan yes. Oracle database. Sorry for not clarifying. Also I edited the question. Would be great if you can help. Thanks!

Comment: what is Uniq_Member_Count?

Comment: select code, condition, count(*) as code_count from table group by code, condition. This is for three columns so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT Code, Cond,
       count( code ) as code_count,
       count( unique case when cond = mm then member end ) As Uniq_Member_Count
FROM (
   SELECT t.*,
          min( cond ) Over (Partition by Member, Code ) As mm
   FROM table1 t
)
GROUP BY  Code, Cond
Order by 1,2
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc772/14

A function: `min( cond ) Over (Partition by Member, Code ) As mm` determines a condition `cond` to which a given member is counted in, if this member belongs to more than 1 condition. 
For example if a given member belongs to conditions A,B,C, then it will be included in a count for A condition (minimum), but not for B,C.
In this example member 3 belongs to `Bad` and `Good` conditions, so it is included in `Bad` count, because `Bad` < `Good`, so the minimum is `Bad`.
I am not sure if my explanation is clear enaugh, sorry for possible confusion.